# Clone has protected access in Object

Tags: java

I don't know why the following program is generating this error-> `clone has protected access in Object`. Can't the derived class access the protected methods of the Object class?  If I skip this statement `cloned.id=(String)id.clone();` the program compiles successfully!

```
class Example implements Cloneable{
String id;
void display(){
    System.out.println("ID="+id);
    }
public Example clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
    Example cloned;
    cloned=(Example)super.clone();
    cloned.id=(String)id.clone();               //troublemaker
    return cloned;
    }
}
class CloneInterface{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try
        {
        Example e1=new Example();
        e1.id="a";
        Example e2=e1.clone();
        e2.id="b";
        e1.display();
        e2.display();
        }
        catch(CloneNotSupportedException e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you cloning a String in the first place? A String is immutable. Cloning it is useless.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451647/how-are-java-lang-objects-protected-methods-protected-from-subclasses

Comment: @JBNizet Why is it generating an error??

Comment: Follow the link posted by Vimsha